# Как из String в java (android) удалить ненужный мне текст?

Tags: java, android, строки

Есть `String` с текстом

```
{7UBZgrChOqNWMOMKNXcVnUK3s972={userName=Ivan Ivanov}}
```

Можно ли как-то оставить только `Ivan Ivanov` с учетом того, что значение `7UBZgrChOqNWMOMKNXcVnUK3s972` - переменное, но с постоянным количеством символов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s = "{7UBZgrChOqNWMOMKNXcVnUK3s972={userName=Ivan Ivanov}}";
String name = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, s.length() - 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String string = "{7UBZgrChOqNWMOMKNXcVnUK3s972={userName=Ivan Ivanov}}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=userName=)[^}]+").matcher(string);
if (matcher.find()) {
   string = matcher.group();
}
```

или короче

```
string = string.replaceAll(".+userName=", "").replace("}}", "")
```

Comment: У @SergeyGornostaev быстрее операция пройдет, через регулярки медленно очень